# How to count characters in VB6 string without including spaces?

Tags: string, vb6

Counting characters in Vb6 without including the spaces (string)

Answer (score 5):

Just use `Len()` and `Replace()` to retrieve the length of your string with the spaces removed. For example:

```
Const strText As String = "The    quick brown  fox"

Debug.Print "Original length:   " & Len(strText)                     ' => 23
Debug.Print "Length w/o spaces: " & Len(Replace$(strText, " ", ""))  ' => 16
```

Comment: Spot on. Note that it isn't necessary to add the $ sign to the `Replace` function as it always returns a String.

Comment: @JC2k8 The `$`-less versions of VB6 functions use `Variant` instead of `String` for their string arguments and return types. Where did you learn that `Replace()` returns a `String` type?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's in the MSDN. You're right about the Variant param tho insofar as that the $-function will fail if the param isn't a String whereas the $-less function will convert the param to String first.

Comment: @JC2k8 I think you're right about `Replace()`. The Object Browser doesn't even show the `$` version and, unlike every other `$`-less string function, it shows `Replace()` using `String` for all string args and the return type. I'll probably continue using `Replace$()` for consistency and stubbornness, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Function NonSpaceCount(ByRef Text As String) As Long
    Dim I As Long
    Dim S As Long

    S = Len(Text)
    Do While S
        S = InStr(I + 1, Text, " ")
        If S Then
            NonSpaceCount = NonSpaceCount + S - (I + 1)
            I = S
        Else
            NonSpaceCount = NonSpaceCount + Len(Text) - I
        End If
    Loop
End Function
```

Speed isn't always everything, but this should be faster than most alternatives.